# Como saber qual CSS está sendo utilizada por uma página?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Pelo inspetor do [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) é possível saber quais `CSS`'s **não** estão sendo utilizadas, como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pergunta é:

> Como saber qual CSS **está** sendo utilizada por uma determinada página?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já utilizei um add-on para o Firefox, para testar, instale o [CSS Usage ADD-ON](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/) e rode na sua página.

Eles vai mostrar qual css está sendo usado e qual não está.

Comment: http://cssdig.com/ para Chrome, porém nunca testei.

Comment: Instalei aqui, onde acho ele no inspetor? Poderia dar uma pequena introdução (na resposta) de como funciona?

Comment: Vc instalou qual? O CSS Usage Add-on ou o cssdig?

Comment: Ah já achei aqui, fica dentro do firebug, a última opção...

Comment: O `CSS Usage Add-on` @guiandmag

Comment: Exatamente, dentro do firebug, na última opção, funcionou?

Comment: Perfeitamente. ^^ Valeu! Em tempo: Seria legal acrescentar na reposta que ele depende do firebug (eu já tinha aqui) e onde encontrar depois de instalado...